# How to estimate the standard error of the percentiles with gamlss::centiles.pred

Tags: r, gamlss

I have fitted a model with

`m0 <- lms(weight,age, data=df)`

After, I use the model to predict percentiles for same ages:

```
newages <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
centiles.pred(m0, xname="age", xvalues= newages, cent= c(5,25,50,75,95))
```

Is it possible to estimate the error of the percentiles predicted? How?

Below a reproducible examples with data include in the gamlss package:

```
library("gamlss")
library("gamlss.data")
data("dbbmi")
m0 <- lms(bmi,age, data=dbbmi, trans.x=TRUE, k=2)
newages <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
percentiles <- centiles.pred(m0, xname="age", xvalues= newages, cent= c(5,25,50,75,95))
```

Comment: Hi There the the error of the percentiles is the square root of the variances which is standard deviation sd(x) function in R where x is a numeric vector. You can try to save  the prediction
x <- centiles.pred(m0, xname="age", xvalues= newages, cent= c(5,25,50,75,95)), I am not sure if the output with be a numeric vector as you didn't share a reproducible example. After save try sd(x)

Comment: This is really a statistical question. Percentiles are a type of order statistic. There are methods. Knowing the correct terms for searching should help. You also might search on “quantile regression”. Voting to close for lack of data. Needs further details before coding examples can be attempted.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you could try bootstrapping them. I would parallelize the code since the package is rather slow. On Linux we can conveniently use `parallel::mclapply`, which is the parallel version of `lapply`. We might silence the function a little using `capture.output`. I demonstrate this with example from `?centiles.pred`.

```
library('gamlss')
a <- gamlss(y ~ pb(x), sigma.fo=~pb(x), data=abdom, family=BCT)
newx <- seq.int(12, 40, 2)
cent <- centiles.pred(a, xname="x", xvalues=newx)

library(parallel)
set.seed(42)
system.time(
  b <- mclapply(seq_len(299L), \(i) {
    X <- abdom[sample.int(nrow(abdom), nrow(abdom), replace=TRUE), ]
    nul <- capture.output(a <- gamlss(y ~ pb(x), sigma.fo=~pb(x), data=X, family=BCT))
    newx <- seq.int(12, 40, 2)
    nul <- capture.output(r <- as.matrix(centiles.pred(a, xname="x", xvalues=newx)[-1]))
    `rownames<-`(r, newx)
  }, mc.cores=7L) |> simplify2array()
)
#    user  system elapsed 
# 743.861   7.524 147.565
```

Using `simplify2array` gives us an `"array"` on which we can `apply` `sd` to get bootstrap standard errors,

```
se <- apply(b, c(1, 2), sd)
```

which we can put into a neat list.

```
(res_lst <- list(centiles=`rownames<-`(cent[-1], cent$x), error=se))
# $centiles
#          0.4         2        10        25        50        75        90        98      99.6
# 12  42.18638  45.94808  50.55402  54.10164  58.10869  62.34625  66.52695  72.67661  78.43236
# 14  63.42588  68.02193  73.57773  77.80866  82.54190  87.49937  92.34611  99.40311 105.93746
# 16  85.55128  90.63694  96.72240 101.31493 106.41336 111.71203 116.85444 124.28015 131.09580
# 18 107.59336 113.00638 119.43694 124.25863 129.58205 135.08375 140.39497 148.01855 154.97127
# 20 128.88564 134.65890 141.48729 146.58710 152.19862 157.97822 163.53955 171.49265 178.71729
# 22 149.23815 155.45232 162.78365 168.24664 174.24610 180.41304 186.33591 194.78788 202.44813
# 24 168.66036 175.43397 183.41582 189.35719 195.87604 202.57063 208.99454 218.15225 226.44314
# 26 187.33960 194.83997 203.67733 210.25491 217.47125 224.88154 231.99167 242.12678 251.30172
# 28 205.35844 213.75354 223.65182 231.02355 239.11539 247.42914 255.41020 266.79334 277.10445
# 30 222.60262 231.96987 243.02502 251.26548 260.31763 269.62507 278.56649 291.32982 302.90129
# 32 239.39290 249.66070 261.78656 270.83041 280.77006 290.99522 300.82306 314.85943 327.59258
# 34 255.89293 266.91077 279.92414 289.63108 300.30058 311.27771 321.82933 336.90114 350.57522
# 36 271.73865 283.47606 297.34085 307.68389 319.05355 330.75203 341.99796 358.06301 372.63969
# 38 286.19116 298.83107 313.77356 324.92838 337.19773 349.82961 361.97990 379.34828 395.11866
# 40 299.29953 313.05326 329.33575 341.50653 354.90804 368.72097 382.02141 401.05688 418.36327
# 
# $error
#         0.4        2       10        25        50        75        90        98      99.6
# 12 8.754073 9.058913 9.772938 10.445019 11.292740 12.268047 13.285140 14.890101 16.699377
# 14 8.302389 8.584919 9.173224  9.690382 10.314486 11.007560 11.707848 12.786696 14.049017
# 16 8.225677 8.403785 8.823087  9.191237  9.630658 10.112131 10.589999 11.319983 12.232993
# 18 8.104683 8.211071 8.524018  8.802718  9.131756  9.485537  9.829230 10.351928 11.051896
# 20 7.913490 7.973818 8.212644  8.426547  8.673893  8.932846  9.178813  9.556925 10.111166
# 22 7.804297 7.807309 7.971309  8.128343  8.311364  8.503114  8.687357  8.989410  9.481017
# 24 7.724357 7.680904 7.792952  7.915895  8.065365  8.227356  8.390109  8.678840  9.171750
# 26 7.649060 7.594180 7.693274  7.808808  7.952233  8.109245  8.266915  8.543402  9.011338
# 28 7.640950 7.599286 7.706000  7.824723  7.970978  8.128637  8.279786  8.520554  8.915502
# 30 7.692231 7.660621 7.777694  7.906453  8.069103  8.248826  8.420955  8.675671  9.053343
# 32 7.811806 7.792124 7.930340  8.081476  8.278466  8.505167  8.731095  9.068910  9.523329
# 34 7.863307 7.907566 8.128554  8.343744  8.613907  8.919423  9.224228  9.679546 10.248512
# 36 7.954630 8.077143 8.398259  8.690299  9.045676  9.439037  9.828830 10.409909 11.104851
# 38 8.265592 8.432389 8.813371  9.153125  9.560848 10.005845 10.443078 11.091570 11.853296
# 40 8.834803 9.000554 9.402092  9.768263 10.208644 10.686466 11.154407 11.851206 12.664367
```